# HTML5 based node-graph editor?

Tags: user-interface, html, graph

I'm looking for an in browser click-n-drag type editor for editing directed labeled graphs.

All I need is a widget to support the editing and the ability to submit (AJAX, form, whatever) the resulting set of origin/label/terminus tuples. It's not what I need it for, but a GUI editor for [simple GraphViz cases](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/fsm.html) would be nearly ideal. This [UML widget](http://old.umlcanvas.org/About) is kinds along the right track.

And I'm kind of restricted to open source, freeware and public domain.

Some other close, but not quite options:

- [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/) (view, not edit. And I don't need the auto layout.)
- [springy](http://dhotson.github.com/springy/demo.html) (ditto.)

Comment: this is probably not what you need... no arrows, dotted lines etc... but you might be able to tweak it, it saves the graphs as json. Code is on github: http://zreference.com/znode/ Hope it's not totally off base.

Comment: @Zevan: please move to an answer. That's the closest I've found so far.

Comment: ok I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could try using Znode. A simple open source flow chart editor I created over the christmas break. It uses jQuery and Raphael. It doesn't really make use of html5 features because I wanted high browser compatability - I've tested in firefox, safari, chrome and ie6-8. It's still in development but it's stable.

Here is more info:
http://www.zreference.com/znode/