# HTML5 canvas, animation and closure libraries

Tags: javascript, canvas, closures

After not finding anything I like with regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877299/html5-based-node-graph-editor) I'm looking to build my own in-browser graph editor. As a first step, I'm looking for a [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/) based library to draw objects on a canvas where so I can do things like update an objects definition and trigger a redraw without to much complication.

---

From a breef look [this lib](https://github.com/rsandor/gury/wiki) looks to do what I want but I see nothing indicating that it's intended to work with closure (and in fact seems to be targeted at jQuery).

Comment: @Phrogz: a) my preference for canvas is weak but based partly on Shiny Object Syndrome. b) see edit/link (4th hit for closure on Google) c) That's partyl due to a large percentage of the questions I ask only getting answers of the form "I don't know how to do that but this things is kinda close". I think it has something to do with often trying to do things (some impossible) that no one has yet figured out how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the question is to spesific: the [standard closure libs contain goog.graphics](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_graphics.html) supporting general drawing primitives that white washes over the difference between canvas, SVG and VML to give a general retained graphics mode effect via each. [goog.graphics.createGraphics](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/4/trunk/closure/goog/docs/closure_goog_graphics_graphics.js.html) selects the 'best' implementation based on what platform is being used.